# Get output line by line from another function (another source file)?

Tags: c

I have two source files: counter.c and main.c:

counter.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int counter(void) {

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%d\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int counter(void);

int main(void) {

    char *line;

    counter();

    return 0;
}
```

What I want to do is to have each line that counter() prints to be assigned to the line variable so I can do printf("%s\n", line) myself in main.c.

**(edit) Unfortunately, this example doesn't translate well to my actual code so maybe I'll just put it here:**

https://github.com/venetwork/venet/blob/master/venet-show.c

What I need is to access the result of running this code on a line by line basis in a different source file (GTK3 GUI). The main function for my combined code will be in this file so main() in venet-show.c should be changed to, say, show(). As of this moment I just use an IO Channel (https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-IO-Channels.html) to "stream" the output of venet-show.c to the GUI but I want to get ride of it. Any ideas?

Comment: Some hints. Start to allocate your array `line` (dynamicly or staticly as you prefer). Then pass it as an argument to your function, and finally use `sprintf` to print in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we pass an allocated memory address and not a pointer like you had to the function. This has storage for the result. Use the return snprintf to advance the pointer so not to overwrite previous results.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int counter(char *answer, size_t array_len) {

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        size_t chars_printed = snprintf(answer, array_len, "%d\n", i);
        answer+=chars_printed;
        array_len-=chars_printed;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(void) {

    char line[10000];

    counter(line, sizeof(line));

    printf("%s", line);

    return 0;
}
```